# PHP: how to analyzing a search expression and retrieve values?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex

I am trying to build a search system and retrieving matching records. in this case.. i wanna let users use some especial chars for exactly build their requests. so i put these signs and then converting them to a correct SQL:
**+** should be converted ro **AND** 
**/** should be converted ro **OR**
**"** should be converted ro **(** or **)**
for example when user entered: **"book/pen"+paper**
it should be converted to SQL WHERE clause: 
**( (myfield LIKE "%book%") OR (myfield LIKE "%pen%") ) AND ( myfield LIKE "%paper%")**
i implemented this with a switch case and arrays.. but i guess that there are another quick way to do that (such as regEx). have you any idea for solving it?
**NOTE 1:** I should collect all term from this expression and save them in another table. so, i need to collect them in an array.
**NOTE 2:** terms can be write in all world languages! from English to Arabic,Persian,.. may be Chinese!!!! 

Thanks

Comment: what is the difference between / and "?

Comment: quotes means parentheses, will override the defined precedence of the operators in an expression but slash means OR in SQL syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try with :

```
$str = '"book/pen"+paper';
// First: replace all keywords (assuming they don't contain " / + by SQL LIKE
$str = preg_replace('#([^"/+]+)#', "(myfield LIKE '%$1%')", $str);
// then replace / by OR
$str = preg_replace("#/#", " OR ", $str);
// then replace + by AND
$str = preg_replace("#\+#", " AND ", $str);
// and finaly replace pair of "" by ()
$str = preg_replace('/"([^"]+)"/', "($1)", $str);
echo $str,"\n";
```

**output:**

```
((myfield LIKE '%book%') OR (myfield LIKE '%pen%')) AND (myfield LIKE '%paper%')
```

Comment: Fantastic... i test it! works with all languages. but.. because of NOTE 1, is there any way to convert all " / + to a charaster like # then explode string to retrieve all word? (eg. "book/pen"+paper convert to #book#pen#paper ) - (eg. "red sky/sunset" -> #red sky#sunset)

Comment: thnx... i solve this with mixing your great way and preg_replace_callback() to retrieve each term and manipulating them! you're the best :)

Answer (score 0):

Considering your example "book/pen"+paper, the following steps should work.

```
    $sourceQuery = '"book/pen"+paper';
    $targetQuery = preg_replace(
                   '/^"(.*)[//](.*)"[/+](.*)$/',
                   '( (myfield LIKE "%$1%") OR (myfield LIKE "%$2%") ) AND ( myfield LIKE "%$3%")',
                   $sourceQuery);
```

To match more than one operators in a place in your source query, use pattern ranges like [\|+]
Read about [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to match any kind of patterns that you wish to use.

For the language question, have your experienced any problems while using non English language.

Comment: thx emaillenin..but I should find a way that can answer in all search expressions nor just this sample.